# Running Fishers (1996) 'Local Offset Viewshed' with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed

Can ArcGIS Desktop run the `Local offset viewshed` as described by (Fisher, 1996) on page 1300-1301 below?

There's a similar operation called 'Invisibility depth' available through the plug-in 'Advanced viewshed analysis' for QGIS, but I'm looking for an alternative for comparison purposes.

[image]

[image]

Fisher, Peter F. "Extending the applicability of viewsheds in landscape planning." Photogrammetric Engineering and Remote Sensing 62.11 (1996): 1297-1302. http://info.asprs.org/publications/pers/96journal/november/1996_nov_1297-1302.pdf